# How to put popup message inside unordered list

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
 if (rnk <5)

<li><a href="rank.aspx" title="Rank" >Rank</a></li>
```

For example above, I wish to popup a message tell user that they are not allow to enter the site if rank less than 5. Can anyone show me how to write the code?

Comment: You need to make it clearer and also to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Shomz if (rnk <5) { document.write('<li><a href="rank.aspx" title="Rank" >Rank</a></li>'); } else if { document.write('alert'); } This i tried so far, actually I want when I click on the 'Rank', it can direct show me the popup message.

Comment: Alright, I wrote you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (rnk > 5) {
     document.write('<li><a href="rank.aspx" title="Rank" >Rank</a></li>'); 
} else { 
     document.write('<li><a href="javascript: alert(\'No Access!\')" title="Rank" >Rank</a></li>'); 
}
```

Try something like this.

Comment: the box can popout but message cant be display